# meaning of a difficult sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I came across a sentence, which I am utterly incapable of understanding.
I can , at the first place , not  understand meaning of  verb " dispatch " here . 
Why has the writer used this verb with  'as'?
Has the writer used " had a brisk way of dispatching " as an idiom ? 
My reason for this is that we have an idiom " have a way of doing sth ".

> Whether the world is made of matter, spirit or green
>   cheese is not a question over which Marx lost much sleep. He
>   was disdainful of such large metaphysical abstractions, and
>   had a brisk way of dispatching them as idly speculative. As
>   one of the most formidable minds of modernity, Marx was
>   notably allergic to fancy ideas.

The text is from a book by Terry Egelton

Comment: Marx did not lose much sleep over the question “Is the world made of matter or is it made of spirit or is it made of green cheese?”

Comment: He believed they [such questions] were just idle speculation and dispatched them in a brisk way.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Thank you.but how could I that understand?Is there a rule or explaination?

Comment: Subject-verb inversion?

Comment: No.the usage of 'dispatch ' with "as".what do you think about jeremy's answer?

Comment: Think of it as “as being” -  dispatched as being idle speculation

Comment: "*As*" applies to "*dispatching*", not "*way*". It's clumped as follows: "... brisk way of (dispatching them as idly speculative)."

Comment: *Dispatched* here means ***dismissed***. Marx rejected those abstractions, tossing them out summarily because he saw them as useless - only speculative, with no practical utility.

Answer (score 2):

> Whether the world is made of matter, spirit or green cheese is not a
> question over which Marx lost much sleep.

The assertion being that as Marx did not lose much sleep, the above question bothered him very little if at all...

> He was disdainful of such large metaphysical abstractions...
>
> [Metaphysical : Based on abstract reasoning.- [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/metaphysical)]

He had no respect for thinking about these abstract and for the most part unanswerable type questions.

> and had a brisk way of dispatching them as idly speculative.
>
> [Dispatch : 1. Send off to a destination or for a purpose. - [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dispatch)]

**Dispatching** is being used figuratively here, he would send the questions away as not being worth entertaining, as such questions were lazy and with no definitive answers (*idle speculation*).

> As one of the most formidable minds of modernity, Marx was notably allergic to fancy ideas.

The last part of the passage conveys an opinion of the author that most modern great minds do not like (are *allergic to*) such fancy ideas (of the abstract, metaphysical nature) previously suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Standard idiom: having a [particular] way of doing something

The use of "dispatch ... as" is unusual; I would suggest the writer has "borrowed" it from the synonymous and more usual construction "dismiss ... as".

Answer (score 1):

[Marx] had a brisk way of dispatching [those notions] as [being] idly speculative.

In other words, Marx spared no extra time or energy to spend on ideas that could not be proven.

It's not an idiom. It's meant literally. He dismissed those ideas quickly, as he had no time to spend on them.

Comment: Ah.so do you believe that "as "mean here "because of"?

Comment: More, "because he saw them as," but yes.

Comment: Technically, one would use "as being" but "being" is omitted for style.